# Which GPIO pins does the 2.4 inch monitor use (for Pi Zero)

Tags: gpio, hardware, display, pi-zero, electronics

Which GPIO pins does the [2.4 inch Adafruit monitor](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-2-4-pitft-hat-with-resistive-touchscreen-mini-kit) use on the Pi Zero?

I am an amateur at soldering so I would only like to solder the minimum amount of pins in order to minimize the risk of messing it up. So, I would like to know which pins are used by the monitor for general purpose use.

Here is the GPIO layout: 
[image]

please could you show me which ones are used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [Adafruit's documentation](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-2-4-pitft-hat-with-resistive-touchscreen-mini-kit) for the screen:

> This design uses the hardware SPI pins (SCK, MOSI, MISO, CE0, CE1) as
>   well as GPIO #25 and #24. All other GPIO are unused.

The Zero shares the same 40-pin GPIO arrangement as other Pis - you can figure out which pins are which at the extremely helpful [pinout.xyz](https://pinout.xyz/#).

Comment: Ok, but I assume it uses the power pins too, and a ground pin, in that case which one?